# How to manage command parameters when using programmatic menu

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm using a MenuContribution to feed a menu entry, implementing a feature like the "switch workspace" in E3.
In a dynamic menu contribution, i'm building a 3 item list of most recent opened projects followed by the "Other.." entry.
graphically, i'm done, the 3 list, separator and "other.." menu elements are showing up.

But in the case of most recent project, i have to dynamically pass the project name/Path to the handler which consume the selection event.
below is a code similar to what i have in the menu contribution that creates one of the 3 recent project item :

```
@AboutToShow
public void aboutToShow(List<MMenuElement> items, MApplication application) {

        MHandledMenuItem dynamicItem = modelService.createModelElement(MHandledMenuItem.class);
        dynamicItem.setLabel(projectName);
        dynamicItem.setContributorURI("platform:/plugin/com.acme");

        MCommand command = modelService.createModelElement(MCommand.class);
        command.setElementId(LOAD_PROJECT_COMMAND_ID);

        MCommandParameter commandParam = modelService.createModelElement(MCommandParameter.class);
        commandParam.setElementId(PROJECT_NAME_PARAMETER_ID);
        commandParam.setName(PROJECT_NAME_PARAMETER_ID);        
        command.getParameters().add(commandParam);

        // one of the 3 last used projects
        String projectName = "foo";

        dynamicItem.setCommand(command);
        items.add(dynamicItem);
}
```

where LOAD_PROJECT_COMMAND_ID and PROJECT_NAME_PARAMETER_ID are e4xmi command and command parameter id. 
I wonder how i can put projectName in the command to be able to get it back in the associated handler, which contains something like :

```
@Execute
public void execute(ParameterizedCommand command) {
[...]
}
```

Note : I read [Lars tutorial about menus](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#menuadvanced_dynamic) but did not found solution in there

--- EDIT : full contribution code ---

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.ECommandService;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.AboutToShow;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.MApplication;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.commands.MCommand;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.commands.MParameter;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.MDirectMenuItem;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.MHandledMenuItem;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.MMenuElement;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.MMenuSeparator;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EModelService;

import com.acme.model.platypus.extractionresult.CampaignResultProvider;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class SwitchProjectMenuContribution {

    private static final String NEW_PROJECT = "Other...";

    private static final String LOAD_PROJECT_COMMAND_ID = "gui.rcp4.command.loadProjectCommand";
    private static final String PROJECT_NAME_PARAMETER_ID = "gui.rcp4.command.loadProjectCommand.projectName";

    @Inject
    CampaignResultProvider campaignResultProvider;

    @Inject
    private EModelService modelService;

    @Inject
    ECommandService commandService;

    private MDirectMenuItem otherProjectItem;

    private MMenuSeparator separatorItem;

    private MCommand loadProjectCommand;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize(MApplication application) {

        loadProjectCommand = (MCommand) modelService
                .findElements(application, LOAD_PROJECT_COMMAND_ID, MCommand.class, Collections.EMPTY_LIST).get(0);

        otherProjectItem = modelService.createModelElement(MDirectMenuItem.class);
        otherProjectItem.setLabel(NEW_PROJECT);
        otherProjectItem.setContributorURI("platform:/plugin/com.acme.gui.rcp4");
        otherProjectItem.setContributionURI(
                "bundleclass://com.acme.gui.rcp4/com.acme.gui.rcp4.handlers.OtherProjecthandler");

        separatorItem = modelService.createModelElement(MMenuSeparator.class);
    }

    @AboutToShow
    public void aboutToShow(List<MMenuElement> items, MApplication application) {

        String[] lastProject = campaignResultProvider.getLastUsed();
        MMenuElement newEntry;
        for (String projectName : lastProject) {
            newEntry = createExistingProjectEntry(projectName);
            items.add(newEntry);
        }
        if (lastProject.length > 0) {
            items.add(separatorItem);
        }
        items.add(otherProjectItem);

    }

    private MHandledMenuItem createExistingProjectEntry(String projectPath) {

        MHandledMenuItem dynamicItem = modelService.createModelElement(MHandledMenuItem.class);
        dynamicItem.setLabel(projectPath);
        dynamicItem.setContributorURI("platform:/plugin/com.acme.gui.rcp4");

        MParameter commandParam = modelService.createModelElement(MParameter.class);
        commandParam.setName("projectName");
        commandParam.setElementId(PROJECT_NAME_PARAMETER_ID);
        commandParam.setValue(projectPath);

        dynamicItem.getParameters().add(commandParam);
        dynamicItem.setCommand(loadProjectCommand);

        return dynamicItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the parameter value to the `MHandledMenuItem` not the command.

Use a `MParameter` and call the `setName` and `setValue` methods to set the name (must match the parameter name in the command) and value (the project name in your case).

Add the `MParameter` to the `MHandledMenuItem.getParameters()` list.

Note: You should only define the command and command parameter once, not every time `aboutToShow` is called (so that should probably be in the e4xmi file).

Comment: Are you sure for the reuse of MParameter? if i reuse the same one for 5 different menu item, i think there will be "value" property clash (i have a loop in the real "aboutToShow()" body

Comment: It is MCommand and MCommandParameter you only need to create once. MHandledMenuItem and MParameter are one per menu item.